# descargar imagen captcha con puppeteer

Tags: puppeteer

Hola que tal estoy teniendo un problema al descargar la imagen captcha de una web, el problema es que cada vez que lo genera la imagen esta en blanco y la verdad no se porque sucede eso

```
    const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
    const fs = require('fs');
    var request = require('request');
    const getUsername = 'jarbulua';
    const chromeOptions = {
      executablePath:'C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe',
      headless:false, 
      slowMo:10,
      defaultViewport: null
    };

(async function main() {

    const browser = await puppeteer.launch(chromeOptions);    
    const page = await browser.newPage();

    await page.goto('http://extraweb.movistar.com.pe/PortalCanales/Login/frmLogin.aspx');

    // este el usuario de login  
    await page.type('#ctl00_Contenido_usuario',getUsername);


// download function para descargar imagen

    const download = async function (uri, filename, callback) {
      request.head(uri, function (err, res, body) {
          console.log('content-type:', res.headers['content-type']);
          console.log('content-length:', res.headers['content-length']);
          request(uri).pipe(fs.createWriteStream(filename)).on('close', callback);
      });
    };

        let imageLink = await page.evaluate(() => {
          const image = document.querySelector('#ctl00_Contenido_imgCaptcha');
          return image.src;
      });

       await download(imageLink, 'myImage.png', function () {
            console.log('done');
        });

})()
```

Este es la parte que genera la descarga de la imagen

```
// download function para descargar imagen

    const download = async function (uri, filename, callback) {
      request.head(uri, function (err, res, body) {
          console.log('content-type:', res.headers['content-type']);
          console.log('content-length:', res.headers['content-length']);
          request(uri).pipe(fs.createWriteStream(filename)).on('close', callback);
      });
    };

        let imageLink = await page.evaluate(() => {
          const image = document.querySelector('#ctl00_Contenido_imgCaptcha');
          return image.src;
      });

       await download(imageLink, 'myImage.png', function () {
            console.log('done');
        });
```

El objetivo es descargar la imagen haber si me pueden dar una mano por favor

Comment: Y para que quieres descargar esa imagen? Si puedes crear tu propio captcha

Comment: Hola Rimuru, lo que sucede es que lo quiero descargar con el fin de usar tesseract ocr nodejs para convertirlo en texto y así de esa manera pueda resolver el captcha.
Bueno en realidad es lo único que se me ocurrió para resolver el captcha.

Comment: Pero con que propósito quieres hacer eso?

Comment: Mi propósito es es loguearme en la web, y donde estoy estancado es en resolver ese captcha de imagen.
Estoy automatizando el Logueo en pocas palabras.

Comment: Seria mas simple hacerlo de manera manual, ya que si el sistema de esa pagina detecta que es un bot o sistema automatizado de logueo, te bloqueara la cuenta de manera permanente